# how to create two jars from one Maven project but with different resources files

Tags: java, maven

I have a single maven project that has multiple folders in src/main/resources, I want to generate two Jars, one include src/main/resources/folder1/all properties and the other include src/main/resources/folder2/all properties.

Is their a way to achive this ? If not, what is the simplest way to achive my goal?

Comment: That feels like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you elaborate a little on what you want to achieve in the end? There for sure are ways to do this but those probably already require a good amount of "scripting" in order to create 2 jars out of 1 maven project.

Comment: I would still do a separation in a multi-module project, your current one as a "library" module, and two modules with different resources.

Comment: Split into at least two modules. One for each jar. Any other approach will cause you more pain in the long run.

Comment: i have to generate 2 jars with the same java code but different properties files, each property file relates to an application server (tomcat, websphere)
The two jars must be generated when launching the build with mvn install command

Comment: Maybe [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) can suits your needs

Comment: Why does the configuration of those jars depend on the server they're deployed in? That seems like bad design to me and I'd try to split the 2 apart, much like Joop Eggen already suggested: use a single jar as a shared library and put the properties somewhere else, e.g. another lib that depends on the app server, the application that uses it, or externalize it altogether. In the end you'd very likely want different properties for different environments anyway - even if those environments use the same app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then you can use "**Maven Assembly plugin**" and "**The Assembly Descriptor**" in the following way:
first of all, you can not use a *profile* if you want to build 2 jar files simultaneously.
So, my suggestion is to exclude your config files from your jar then use Maven Assembly plugin to create a different zip file with these folders.

for example, in your case you should have 2 file descriptors like the following:

```
               <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>folder1</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/java/descriptors/folder1.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and `folder1.xml` contains:

```
<assembly>
    <id>folder1</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>
                target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-yourJar.jar
            </source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/folder1</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/config</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

for "folder2" you can do it in the same way.

also for exclude some config files from the jar you can use this plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>                    
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <mainClass>package.path.to.your.main.class.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Using maven-resources-plugin as follows:

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-resources</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Introduction to Build Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

> Profiles can be activated in the Maven settings, via the  section. This section takes a list of  elements, each containing a profile-id inside.

```
<settings>
  ...
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>profile-1</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
 ...
</settings>
```

> Profiles listed in the  tag would be activated by default every time a project use it.
> Profiles can be automatically triggered based on the detected state of the build environment. These triggers are specified via an  section in the profile itself. Currently, this detection is limited to prefix-matching of the JDK version, the presence of a system property or the value of a system property.

This allows to create a different package content based on the target environment.